# KPI Calculation dont unterstand the formula

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

We got a KPI from our customer which we don't really understand. As we tried to input the formula in wolfram alpha we only get the answer that it doesn't understand our query. Maybe one of you guys can help us to understand and how to calculate the KPI.

Formula Image:
[Picture of formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eWfB.jpg)

| Thresholds | Seconds |
| --- | --- |
| Group 0 | 18.3 |
| Group 1 | 8.2 |
| Group 2 | 5.9 |
| Group 3 | 2.4 |
| Group 4 | 4.7 |
| Group 5 | 1.2 |
| Group 6 | 2.2 |

| Variable | Definition | Description | Unit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T Durchschnitt/Average | Average value | Calculated monthly average value of the measurement | Seconds |
| T Schwellwert/Threshold | Target value in seconds | Agreed threshold value | Seconds |
| n | Number of target measurements | Number of defined target values for which measurements are taken | Quantity |

We have the following Measured Numbers:

| Measured Average | Seconds |
| --- | --- |
| Group 0 | 7.21 |
| Group 1 | 4.5 |
| Group 2 | 2.51 |
| Group 3 | 1.31 |
| Group 4 | 1.95 |
| Group 5 | 1.86 |
| Group 6 | 1.92 |

Could someone try to explain to us where we have to insert which numbers? If possible, we would appreciate a screenshot of how this should be entered in wolfram alpha, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used Wolfram Alpha, but most likely it does not understand your query because the expression is Boolean arithmetic, an expression that does not make sense in mathematics but is common in the programming world.

The expression $T_{D}-T_{S}>0$ is a boolean expression, i.e. the value is either `True` or `False`. In most programming language, you can sum boolean expression: they will treat `True` as $1$ and `False` as $0$. Therefore, the expression

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(T_{D}-T_{S}>0\right)
$$

gives us the number of measurements in which the group average exceeds the threshold. Now, the KPI should be defined as

$$
\frac{n-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(T_{D}-T_{S}>0\right)}{n}
$$

which will give us the ratio of the number of measurements in which the group average **does not** exceed the threshold to the total number of measurements. Notice that the indices should go from $0$ to $n-1$ instead of $n$.